# What are Indian missiles named after?

Tags: military, india

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agni_(missile)) says that Indian missiles are named after the five elements in nature -

> The Agni missile (अग्नि IAST: Agni "Fire") is a family of medium to intercontinental-range ballistic missiles developed by India, named after one of the five elements of nature.

However, it doesn't mention the source of its info.

[Asian Society](https://asiasociety.org/gauri-and-prithvi-nuclear-south-asia#:%7E:text=Prithvi%20is%20named%20for%20Hindu,name%20of%20new%20Indian%20missile.) says that Indian missiles are named after either Hindu gods or ancient Hindu kings -

> Prithvi is named for the Hindu general who fought Muslim invaders. Agni (Hindu God of fire) is the name of the new Indian missile. Indian nuclear explosions were called Shakti (goddess and also the name of power).

Various Indian newspaper articles on this topic seem dubious as they don't name any specific person to be their source of information.

My doubts accentuate as the MBTs of India are named after heroes from the Hindu scripture *Mahabharata* - [***Arjun***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjun_(tank)) and [***Bhishma***](https://tanks-encyclopedia.com/modern/India/T-90_bhishma.php).

What are Indian missiles named after - Hindu gods or natural elements?

Comment: Can't it be both? There are only five classical Indian elements, seven if you throw in the Chinese ones, so you run out rather quickly.

Comment: Also,  pṛthvī (पृथ्वी) means earth in addition to being the name of a queen, doesn't it?

Comment: @Obie2.0, *Can't it be both?* --- Yes, it cab, but what is the reference/source of the info?

Comment: If you look at a list of just India's surface to surface misiles, only agni and prithvi are represented from the classical elements. The other missiles are called dhanush, shaurya, and prahaar, which are not elements.

Comment: There is also the akash missile (ākāśa, void), which is surface to air.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that *that specific missile* is named after an element of nature. It doesn't claim that *all* Indian missiles are named after them.

Comment: In late 8os - early 90s India developed two ballistic missile families - short-range "Prithvi" ("Earth") and long-range "Agni" ("Fire"). Note that in both cases these words are both the name for a natural element and the name of the god of the corresponding element. Later missiles seem to have left this naming convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Times of India covered this in [an article](https://m.timesofindia.com/india/how-missiles-get-their-names/articleshow/3147147.cms). The names of missile and other products are given in a way that has "functional meaning and/or a scientific rationale". The director and the team proposes names and selects one which they like most according to the functionality of the product. Sanskrit names are always preferred.

That rationale applies. For example, Prithvi (meaning Earth) missiles are surface to surface. Rudram means "remover of sorrows". It is an anti-radiation missile. Brahmos is a joint venture between India and Russia, its name is taken from the rivers Brahmaputra and Moskva.

Also regarding the tanks' names', note that [Zorawar tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorawar_LT) are not named after Mahabharata character. It is a Punjabi word meaning "brave and strong".